# file_get_contents by div id

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to get the content of a specific div (id="total_raised") from an external webpage (https://uconn.givecorps.com/projects/3120-uconn-marching-band-tower-project). Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://uconn.givecorps.com/projects/3120-uconn-marching-band-tower-project';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="total_raised">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

When I echo $content, everything displays fine. But when I try to echo just the dollar amount raised, nothing shows up.

Comment: The `<div>` in the page does not match what you are exploding on first. Try looking at the source of the page and you would see it also includes a few classes. Also, this is pretty easy to accomplish using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/domdocument). Once loaded, you could just [getElementById](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementbyid) and get the value from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your explode code like this:

```
$first_step = explode( "id='total_raised'>" , $content );
$second_step = explode("<span>" , $first_step[1] );
$raised = trim($second_step[0]);
```

Or you could use `DOMDocument` for a more precise way to do it:

```
$url = 'https://uconn.givecorps.com/projects/3120-uconn-marching-band-tower-project';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($content);

$raised = explode("\n", trim($doc->getElementById('total_raised')->nodeValue))[0];

echo $raised; // $2,405
```